# Flickr API get image based on location

Tags: flickr

Is it possible through flickr api or some other service obtain CC-images taken at the location the user is situated?

Like getting the lat and long from the browser and sending it to flickr and then fetching an image taken there? Similar to how the yahoo app on iOS does.

Comment: You could try searching by tags.

Comment: Google is your friend: http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.geo.photosForLocation.html

Comment: Yahoo weather iOS app has the feature you described

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [flickr API documentation for `flickr.photos.search`.](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html)

There are optional lat, lon, radius and geo-context parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example url showing the format for an endpoint to search for photos at a specific location:

https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=e693af3d1f05789dfaad53030d8ba9e2&lat=37.7994&lon=122.3950&format=rest&api_sig=b5935d841e55cb4281b9c84701422ae8

I tested the endpoint in postman and in my browser, and it returns an xml including photos tagged to the lat and lon I specified.

The example was created thanks to some documentation here: [https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.geo.photosForLocation.html](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.photos.search)

And the ever handy Flickr api explorer tool: https://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.photos.search

Comment: https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.geo.photosForLocation.html 
  should be     
  https://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.photos.search

Comment: I'll update. The original link still redirects to the right place, but can't expect that to hold up forever. Thanks!